# Why are these guidelines appearing on my image in Photoshop 2014?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

Since updating to Creative Cloud, Photoshop 2014, guidelines have started appearing. In trying to screenshot it I figured out it occurs when pressing the Ctrl key on an editable layer. However, I'm not sure all of the features (new I presume) and don't see it in the Keyboard Shortcut listings to change.

Does anyone know the correct name for the feature, and what it can do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed this as well. It seems they integrated this new feature into `Smart Guides` where it shows you the distance from neighboring layers. Although helpful it can get really annoying when you're just trying to <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>select layers</kbd>. The only solution I've found thus far is just turning Smart Guides off.

Answer (score 2):

**Distances from the canvas**:

When you hold down the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (Windows) key while hovering outside a shape, Photoshop displays distances from the canvas.

[here a description](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/whats-new.html#Smart%20Guides)

probably you can disable this behaviour by unchecking the Measurement label mark like on Illustrator (I don't have a CC Photoshop, so re-check it) -

[image]